# Cambiar valor de propiedad al momento de presentarla en tabla mat-table en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mat-table

tengo un arreglo de datos de esta forma:

```js
Data = 
[
   {
     atributo: "titulo",
     id: 11118,
     mapeo: ""
   },
   {
     atributo: "fecha",
     id: 11119,
     mapeo: "fecha"
   },
   {
     atributo: "abstract",
     id: 11120,
     mapeo: "abstract"
   }
]
```

Estoy ocupando `MatTableDataSource` para hacer una `Table Data Source`, tengo un método para obtener los datos llamado `getConfiguracion()` donde hago lo siguiente:

```js
getConfiguracion(){
    console.log("DATA", this.Data)
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.Data);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

Y en el `html` tengo lo siguiente:

```html
 <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="atributo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Atributo </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.atributo}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="mapeo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Mapeo </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.mapeo}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

El problema que tengo es que en el primer objeto de mi `Data` la propiedad `mapeo` tiene un string en blanco y al momento de mostrar en la tabla obviamente no muestra nada.

```
{
   atributo: "titulo",
   id: 11118,
   mapeo: ""
}
```

Cómo puedo hacer para que en caso de que la propiedad mapeo esté vacía me pinte en la tabla la propiedad `mapeo` con `titulo`, solo necesito que se pinte en la tabla sin necesidad de modificar el arreglo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Dejo un stackblitz de lo que tengo actualmente: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-data-source-jyfcdu?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar una condición en la interpolación para cambiar dinámicamente lo que se muestra en la vista. Por ejemplo en tu caso sería de verificar si el valor de la propiedad mapeo esta vacía entonces debe mostrar el valor de la propiedad atributo. Caso contrario que muestre el valor de la propiedad mapeo.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="mapeo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Mapeo </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.mapeo!='' ? element.mapeo : element.atributo }}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```